# How would a client edit the website?

Tags: html, css, clients, change-management

I am wanting to start creating websites for clients but am wondering on somethings. This one I do not know how to put into Google to get the results I want so I am asking here. I do HTML/CSS site making(I hear php is better but don't have the knowledge of it atm) but when I give the client their website, how can they edit the text without having to go into say Dreamweaver?

Comment: Assuming you are providing HTML to the client, how they do this would be up to them. They should always have access to their own site content and sever. This is proper. The site owner should be able to edit the HTML using anything from notepad to Dreamweaver and deploy it using FTP or a control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advice that you look into using a CMS system like WordPress. It's possible to do so without having to install anything yourself as many providers offer you to just click, click, click, and voilà your site is installed. The hardest part for you will be to tweak the resulting HTML and CSS so it works as expected by your client. But finding an existing theme and tweaking that should give you much more power immediately.

The CMS account can be made under your customer's name and credit card so that way they are responsible for all the fees. Until you feel confident enough to run your own server... (although frankly it's a lot of work as you have to make sure all the websites get updated quickly all the time! So in the end you don't really make more money that way, except maybe that you lock your customers in with your agency.)

Asking customers to edit HTML is probably not going to fly very high with most. Not only that, people are not unlikely to do stupid things like edit the file with MS-Word and then upload the .doc file hoping that is going to replace the existing page... Or they'll smash some tags, add weird characters  that only work under MS-Windows, etc. So many potential problems, I can't imagine anyone doing this unless they know HTML.